# Adding a new book to an array Books()

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have to add a new book to an array Books(). I used a text file to fill the array now I need to ReDim Preserve to add a new book to the array.  This is the ReDim and For Loop I have along with a function to do this but it's not working correctly. Any idea on how to do this.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    Dim newBook As Book
    newBook = EmptyBook()

    ReDim Preserve Books(Books.Count)

    For i As Integer = 0 To Books.Count - 1
        Books(i) = newBook
    Next

End Sub

Function EmptyBook() As Book
    Dim Answer As Book
    With Answer
        .title = txtTitle.Text
        .authorLastName = txtAuthor.Text
        .year = CInt(txtYear.Text)
        .value = CDec(txtValue.Text)
    End With
    Return Answer
End Function
```

Comment: Show your way of filling the array and your other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

Dim newBook As Book
newBook = EmptyBook()

if Books is nothing then
  ReDim Books(0)
else
  ReDim Preserve Books(Books.GetUpperBound(0) + 1)
end if

Books(Books.GetUpperBound(0)) = newBook 

End Sub
```